# Get specific number from a string after specific character is detected by preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I want to cut number after string "NPWP" and take all number after that.

Sometimes i have a string like this:

```
$valueDetail['DTL02CNA'] = NPWP:016386112436000 JALAN ELANG DESA SUKAHATI CITEUREUP BOGOR 16810, INDONESIA TEL:+62(21)8765105
```

and sometime like this:

```
$valueDetail['DTL02CNA'] = NPWP 314633389431000 DELTA SILICON INDUSTRIALL PARK 3 JL PINANG F 16/25A, CICAU CIKARANG PUSAT, CITY: BEKASI, JB 17550 INDONESIA
```

From example above, i need the result like this:

```
016386112436000
314633389431000
```

Now, I just know how to identify it

```
<?= preg_match("/npwp/i", $valueDetail['DTL02CNA'] ) ?  '<label class="label label-success">NPWP Is Exist</label>' : 'Tidak Ada NPWP' ?> <br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match from the beginning of the string `^`, match `NPWP` followed by an optional colon `:?` and zero or more whitespace characters `\s*`.

Then you might  use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match and match one or more digits `\d+`:

[`^NPWP:?\s*\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/KhzMVJ/1)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/13Cmm)

Another option could be to match capture your value in the first capturing group `(\d+)`:

[`^NPWP:?\s*(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/KhzMVJ/2)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/W8eIs)

Comment: @FadlyDzil Then you could use the case insensitive flag `/i` for example [Demo](https://3v4l.org/eul6G)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegEx [`(?<=NPWP[^\d]*)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/xGNGAR/2)

- `(?<=NPWP[^\d]*)` makes sure there is `NPWP` and anything but a digit before your match
- `\d+` matches any digit at least once

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/xGNGAR/2)

Comment: Brother, you got error.
NOTICE: No ending delimiter '(' found. Read documentation how to format $pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If your string NPWP and number is exact length, just use `substr()`

```
$number = substr($valueDetail['DTL02CNA'], 5, 15);
```

Comment: Too risky, sometimes customer write those sentence in first : "NPWP:" ,  "NPWP ", "NPWP : ". Sometimes in the end of sentence " ...... NPWP: "